# MS CRM 2013 - Update Opportunity via web service

Tags: c#, crm

I wanted to establish a connection with MSCRM by calling their web service from visual studi and should be able to update an opportunity, if opportunity Id is provided.

The whole process has to exposed as a web service.

Since I am new to MS technologies, having hard time figuring this out.

Downloaded some SDK from MS site. Couldn't achieve what I am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a web reference to "`http://servername/MSCrmServices/2007/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx`" this points to your WSDL.

Then use your web reference to instantiate a new object of that type.

```
CrmDataService.opportunity oppty = new CrmDataService.opportunity();
```

Fill in the properties of the object
Then use the service "Create" method to create the object.

```
DataService.Create(oppty);
```

There will be a minimum set of criteria to create the opportunity.

This should guide you in the right direction to achieve this creation via the web-service instead of the SDK.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quick. We have MSCRM 2013.Is there any link that has detailed step ? Please.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already downloaded the CRM 2013 SDK, it has the class already defined which can be reused to access the CRM from visual studio.

Please go to the folder "SDK\SampleCode\CS\GeneralProgramming\Authentication\AuthenticateWithNoHelp"

Refer to the file AuthenticateWithNoHelp.cs.

Code in this class will help you to get the OrganizationService object which will expose you with the update method and you can do this as follows,

```
Entity entity=new entity("opportunity");
entity.Id=<Guid of the opportunity to update>;
service.Update(entity);
```

Assume that variable service is the OrganizationService object you have retrieved.

This is applicable for both CRM 2011 and 2013.

If you have not downloaded CRM 2013 yet, please get it from here(http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40321).
Hope this helps !!!